# Can you use more than one breeze controller in a web api project?

Tags: asp.net, breeze, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to breeze and would like to know if you can use multiple controllers, in a single project, as long as they are setup as follows:

```
 [BreezeController]
 public class BreezeController : ApiController
 {
  //code here

 }
```

Comment: I need something similar but for different reasons - my Breeze Controller API has grown into a huge monster and every little change I need to deploy to production brings down my live apps for 30second or so.  I want to partition my Breeze controller into multiple API projects so that I can deploy parts of the API without affecting all the apps/services. I was thinking of putting all the static data and lookup tables into a separate API project - any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple `BreezeControllers`, each exposing its own metadata.

I've used this in the past to expose one set of entities for public (and mostly readonly) consumption, and a separate one for authorized admin management of entities.